# Mount LUKS encrypted drive

Tags: filesystems, mount, disk, luks

I have an external NVMe disk that was in my old laptop which is encrypted with LUKS. I need to mount that disk and extract some data out of it so this is what I have tried

```
fdisk -l

/dev/sdc3  2549760 2000408575 1997858816 952.7G Linux filesystem

udisksctl  unlock -b /dev/sdc3

Unlocked /dev/sdc3 as /dev/dm-1.
```

So far so good, however, now I am trying to issue `udisksctl mount -b`  and it won't work with neither `/dev/dm-1` or `/dev/mapper/luks-96a2dfa5-1f16-45fd-895c-f2dd0505dde9` or `/dev/sdc3`, it always says that `Object /org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/dm_2d1 is not a mountable filesystem.`

lsblk -l output

```
sdc                                                                                                    
├─sdc2                                        ext4              8df22661-a1f9-4fc6-aa2d-204c605a1626   
├─sdc3                                        crypto_LUKS       96a2dfa5-1f16-45fd-895c-f2dd0505dde9   
│ └─luks-96a2dfa5-1f16-45fd-895c-f2dd0505dde9 LVM2_member       5EOtDn-9iM0-630j-1gqO-73cc-5FgB-Wk8SlY 
└─sdc1                                        vfat              86F0-B82B
```

Output of `vgs` and `lvs`

```
pmensik-Inspiron-7566% sudo vgs
  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
  VG            #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree 
  elementary-vg   1   2   0 wz--n- 952.65g 21.33g
pmensik-Inspiron-7566% sudo lvs
  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
  LV     VG            Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  root   elementary-vg -wi------- 930.37g                                                    
  swap_1 elementary-vg -wi------- 976.00m
```

Is it because the disk was used for running the Elementary OS and there are several partitions mounted as different filesystems? How can I mount `/home` from such a disk and extract data out of it? Thanks a lot

Comment: Please add `lsblk -f` output (after unlocking the device) to the question. I assume you have and LVM setup on top of the LUKS device so you need to mount the logical volumes and not the physical volume that is `/dev/dm-1`.

Comment: @ajgringo619 `mount: unknown filesystem type 'crypto_LUKS'`

Comment: @VojtechTrefny added

Comment: So yes, it is an LVM setup. It's weird that the logical volumes were not auto-activated. What does `vgs` and `lvs` print?

Comment: @VojtechTrefny added :)

Comment: You should be able to manually activate the LVs using `vgchange -ay elementary-vg` and then mount `/dev/elementary-vg/root`.

Comment: @VojtechTrefny Genius, got it! Saved my day, thanks a lot. Please write this as an answer so I can upvote you :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an [LVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_%28Linux%29) setup so after unlocking the LUKS device you need to mount the root logical volume and not the unlocked device itself. In your case the logical volumes were not auto-activated because `lvmetad` is not running, you can activate them (= tell the system to actually create the logical volume block devices) using `vgchange -ay elementary-vg` and then mount the root logical volume `/dev/elementary-vg/root` using either `mount` or `udisksctl mount -b /dev/elementary-vg/root`.